# Google Cloud SQL dashboard problems

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google Cloud SQL for several projects.

At the moment whenever I try and access my individual instance by clicking on the link in

Google Cloud SQL > Overview (This is in the original version)

It loops around to itself and goes nowhere i.e. I can't access it at all.

Any know issues with this at the moment? This used to work fine and has been working for over a year.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

[image]

Comment: How does the URL that loops look like? It should be something like this:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/<project-number>/sql/instances/<short-instnace-name>/overview

Comment: @Sway even I am facing this issue. Didn't understand now how to get into the cloud sql.

Comment: That looks like the deprecated console. Do you experience the same issue on the [new console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)?

Comment: @TonyTseng if you see in the new console there is no any option to run sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the redirect by going direct to https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect

I got this from the **Go back** link in the notification that was displayed at the top of the new console after being redirected there.

[image]

This takes you back, using a URL in the form:

https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project:123456789 but I have found you can just go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect and then select the appropriate project from the drop down on the left.